# How to put post title in a theme file editor

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

Good Day Everyone I just want to ask if it is possible to put the post title in the Name: under the personal information I want to change the user_name to post title and also how can i add the post title to the custom meta fields

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying all single posts.
 *
 * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#single-post
 *
 * @package Astra
 * @since 1.0.0
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly.
}

get_header(); ?>

<?php if ( astra_page_layout() == 'left-sidebar' ) : ?>

    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>

<?php endif ?>

    <div id="primary" <?php astra_primary_class(); ?>>

        <?php astra_primary_content_top(); ?>
        
        <div class="custom-metafields">
    <ul>
        <h4>
            <strong>I. Personal Information</strong>
        </h4>
        <li><strong>Name: </strong> <?php the_field('user_name'); ?></li>
        <li><strong>Date of Birth: </strong> <?php the_field('Date_Birth'); ?></li>
        <li><strong>Age: </strong> <?php the_field('user_age'); ?></li>
        <li><strong>Occupation: </strong> <?php the_field('user_occupation'); ?></li>
        <li><strong>Marital Status: </strong> <?php the_field('marital_status'); ?></li>
        <br>
        <br>
        <h4>
            <strong>II. Contact Information</strong>
        </h4>
        <li><strong>Email Address: </strong> <?php the_field('email_address'); ?></li>
        <li><strong>Phone Number: </strong> <?php the_field('phone_number'); ?></li>
        <li><strong>Address: </strong> <?php the_field('user_address'); ?></li>
        <br>
        <br>
        <h4>
            <strong>III. Report Details</strong>
        </h4>
            <li><strong>Type of Abuse: </strong> <?php the_field('Type_Abuse'); ?></li>
            <li><strong>Photo Evidence: </strong></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
        <?php astra_content_loop(); ?>

        <?php astra_primary_content_bottom(); ?>

    </div><!-- #primary -->

<?php if ( astra_page_layout() == 'right-sidebar' ) : ?>

    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>

<?php endif ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
<li><strong>Name: </strong> <?php the_title(); ?></li>
```